# SSRS - Calculation expression from two different Dataset

Tags: ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012

I have a report that has 2 dataset (Dataset1 and Dateset2) both have the same fields.  How can I calculate the difference between DataSet1 - Opted In and Dataset 2 - Opted in?

For example: Dataset 1 - Opted In has 5000; Dataset 2 - Opted In has 10000, in the Opted difference column it should provide 5000 difference.

I tried the expression below, but it is not providing the difference result.

```
=Join(Lookup(Fields!Month.Value, Fields!Month.Value,(ReportItems!OptedIn3.Value)-(ReportItems!OptedIn4.Value),"THOR_Monthly"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the query

```
=Fields!OptedIn.Value-Lookup(Fields!Month.Value,Fields!Month.Value,Fields!OptedIn.Value,"DataSet1")
```

change the name of the fields if it is different in your tables